# Is there any way to open Oracle 10 form without browser

Tags: forms, oracle

I am developing a application and want run 10g forms without any browser or hiding the broswer windows after running forms in separate frame.

Answer (score 0):

In formsweb.cfg Set separateFrame=true to open a form in applet and then modify the basejpi.htm to close the browser after running the form. Below is the example for basejpi.htm:
Open the basejpi.htm and go to bottom of the file and you will find the code as below then modify in this section after Body tag:

```
</OBJECT>
<!-- Forms applet definition (end) -->

%HTMLafterForm%

</BODY>
<!-- ADD HERE THE JS CODE FOR CLOSING THE BROWSER WINDOW -->
</HTML>
```

Comment: You've done the easy part; perhaps this would be useful if you actually provided the hard part - what javascript code would you suggest?